# I thought pointers could only point to the same class/datatype?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I thought i knew pointers but then as i study run time polymorphism/dynamic binding, i've seen a very different use for pointers. Here are my 3 questions, they're all regarding the single line code below:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void fun (int x) { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    void fun (int x) { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {

    //--------------------------------------
    //1. Pointer can only hold memory address, 'Derived()' is calling the default constructor it is not a memory address
    //2. What's the point of putting this into heap?
    //3. I thought pointers could only hold memory address of the same datatype/class
    Base* obj = new Derived();
    //--------------------------------------

    obj->fun(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Pointer can only hold memory address, 'Derived()' is calling the default constructor it is not a memory address

The expression here is not `Derived()` (which would indeed construct a temporary object), but `new Derived()`, which is `new`'s specific syntax to allocate and construct an object with dynamic lifetime and return *a pointer* to it. Note that the corresponding `delete` to end the object's lifetime is missing, but see the next point.

> 2. What's the point of putting this into heap?

None. In particular, the lifetime of an object does not affect the use of pointers with it, nor are pointers required for polymorphism (references work just as well). In any case, dynamic allocation should be done with smart pointers, not naked `new`s.

> 3. I thought pointers could only hold memory address of the same datatype/class

That's still true: `obj` is pointing at the `Base` subobject of the `Derived` object. C++ provides an implicit pointer-adjusting conversion from `Derived *` to `Base *` (and `Derived &` to `Base &` as well) to facilitate the use of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Pointer can only hold memory address, 'Derived()' is calling the default constructor it is not a memory address

A `new` expression does multiple things. First, it allocates enough memory for the type of object. Then, it calls the constructor for that type at the allocated memory. Then, it returns a pointer to the newly created object. Pointers point to objects. `new` returns a pointer to an object. So there is no problem here, `obj` will now point to the newly created `Derived` object.

> 2. What's the point of putting this into heap?

It isn't strictly necessary to dynamically create an object here. You could just as easily have the following and illustrate polymorphism :

```
Derived foo;
Base* obj = &foo;
```

Maybe the author of this example didn't think of that, or maybe they wanted to illustrate the mechanics of `new` at the same time. You'd have to ask them.

> 3. I thought pointers could only hold memory address of the same datatype/class

It is true that `obj` is a `Base*` so it can only point to a `Base` type object. But a `Derived` object is also a `Base` object, so `obj` can easily point to a `Derived` object. That is what `public` inheritance achieves. The `: public Base` part of `class Derived : public Base` means `Derived` is also a `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers can point to anything with a memory address.

A pointer to an instance of a derived class can be handled as if it were a pointer to the base class, even if the base class itself is abstract (unable to be instantiated itself). That's how polymorphism works in C++.

Why put a pointer to an object on the stack and the object itself into the heap? Many reasons, some of them good and others not so good.